# Flutter InkWell with text inside RichText with overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a text widget (`RichText` with `overflow` set to ellipsis) with embeddable "clickable" `InkWell`s, so text consists of `TextSpan`s and `WidgetSpan`s with `InkWell` and `Text` inside it.

For example I have a following text: "**Sir Arthur Conan Doyle** wrote **Sherlock Holmes**" where in **bold** are texts that I want to be wrapped with `InkWell` (so they'll have ripple effect on touch). I also want to make text overflowable like a normal one, so ellipsis can occur in inner and outer texts, e.g. following is the desired layouts:

- "**Sir Arthur Conan Doyle** wrote **Sherlock...**" - inner text overflow
- "**Sir Arthur Conan Doyle** wrote..." - outer text overflow
- "**Sir Arthur...**" - inner text overflow; remaining text overflows, but hidden

I'm stuck on a problem that `WidgetSpan` is constrained by paragraph width, so I cant simply make text inside it overflow, means I have no access to "remaining" width instead of "full" width of paragraph.

Comment: Can you include your current snippet

Comment: @YeasinSheikh sure, here: https://dartpad.dev/a92d65958eb8b0de4dd9c791cdad37a5

Answer (score 0):

You can use onEnter(event){} like this

```
Text.rich(
              TextSpan(
                text: 'You don\'t have an account ? ',
                children: [
                  TextSpan(
                    text: 'create an account',
                    /// use this function
                    onEnter: (event){   
                      debugPrint('Hi');
                      // TODO: Create an account
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Question is not about event's of `TextSpan`, but about text overflow behavior. Sadly, your answer isn't applicable to my question, but still thanks for your efforts.